# Semantic shift of worrywart!

Tags: word-usage, american-english, semantic-shift

The informal AmE term worrywart refers to:

> a person who tends to dwell unduly on difficulty or troubles.

but according to a few sources the original meaning of the word was actually its opposite:

> Worrywart is an American term which comes from a comic strip character named Worry Wart which ran from the 1920s through the 1970s. ***Originally, worrywart meant someone who pesters others***, but in time it came to mean someone who frets over the possibility of trouble.([The Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/interesting-words/worrywart-and-worryguts/#:%7E:text=Worrywart%20is%20an%20American%20term,over%20the%20possibility%20of%20trouble.))

And

> Worry Wart was a generic nickname or insult for any character who caused others to worry, which is ***the inverse of the current colloquial meaning.*** ([Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/worry%20wart))

[GDoS](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/iqerjmq#wg2sdta) gives an example of its current meaning from the early 40s, from which we can assume that the semantic change probably started in those years.

> 1. (US) a pathological worrier.

> - 1943    [US]    W. Guthrie Bound for Glory (1969) 58: Okay! Worry Wart, you.

What may have caused this considerable shift in meaning of worrywart?

Comment: I'm not convinced it's a significant shift in meaning. One definition is *someone who worries a lot, especially about unimportant things and **in a way that annoys other people***. The simple derived noun ***worrier*** can mean a person who worries ***about things*** AND / OR a person who worries ***other people*** (both or either may apply in any given case). Personally, I tend to think of a ***worrywart*** as someone whose worrying irritates / inconveniences *me*, but a ***worryguts*** is just a fretful person (whose angst doesn't really concern or bother me; that's *their* problem).

Answer (score 1):

The word "wart" had an origin earlier than the comic strip: OED

> b. colloquial. An obnoxious or objectionable person.
>
> 1896   G. Ade Artie i. 5   *There they was, holdin' to this wart.*

The attributive "worry" seems to have been added for effect. The question then becomes, "when did the transitive version of "worry" in the sense of "bothering/irritating someone" start to have that meaning?

To worry is a very old verb that, originally, meant to strangle, or choke

> c725   Corpus Gloss. S 558   St[r]angulat, **wyrgeð** uel smorað.

It then exteneded to encompass any fatal damage to the throat (usually dogs worrying sheep) but it had weakened in meaning by the 17th century(OED)

> 6. In lighter sense: **To vex, distress, or persecute by inconsiderate or importunate behaviour; to plague or pester with reiterated demands, requests, or the like.**
>
> 1671   J. Milton Samson Agonistes 906 *Witness when I was worried with thy peals.*

This is the sense of the comic strip "Worry Wart".

In the intransitive use, it was not until the mid-19th century that it is recorded:

> 7c. intransitive (for reflexive). **To give way to anxiety or mental disquietude.** ...
>
> 1860   J. E. Worcester Dict. Eng. Lang.   *Worry v.n., to indulge in idle complaining; to fret; to be troubled.* (Colloquial.) *Roget*.
>
> 1861   J. G. Holland Lessons in Life xiii. 181 *When she can find nothing to do, then she worries.*

This shows that at the time of the comic strip hero, both meanings were possible, and both meanings are possible now.

The word itself "worry-wart" in the sense of someone who is neurotic about small things is first recoreded in 1956:

OED

> **worry wart**  n. *colloquial (chiefly U.S.)* **an inveterate worrier, one who frets unnecessarily.**
>
> 1956   I. Belknap Human Probl. of State Mental Hosp. x. 177   *The persevering, nagging delusional group—who were termed ‘worry warts’, ‘nuisances’, ‘bird dogs’, in the attendants' slang.*

I note that there is no note of the sense of *an objectionable person who causes worry in others* in the OED, (and I have never heard of it either) and whereas, absence of evidence is not evidence of absence, I therefore suggest that this is a failed, restricted, or ephemeral coinage.